# x-editable render html error response

Tags: x-editable

We have a system where customer information is editable in-line.
When someone puts in an email that already exists, I want to return the error message:

```
Email already exists. <a href='/find-duplicates/id'>Click here to find possible duplicates of this customer</a>
```

I would like the user to be able to click on the link when s/he sees the error message.  The error message is very easy to send; it's rendering the html that's the problem.

Comment: Whats the problem? You can use success callback. From docs: `success: function(response, newValue) {
        if(response.status == 'error') return response.msg; //msg will be shown in editable form
    }`

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The problem is that the error response cannot be clicked.  I would like to include a link in the error response and the html to be rendered so that the user is able to click on what may be a solution to her problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to display same kind of link in x-editable field error as @iateadonut.

For anyone wanting to display html in x-editable errors, assuming you have the error with html sent back from server with response status code different from 500 (400 maybe) try :

```
$(function() {
  $('#your_field_id').editable({
    error: function(response, newValue) {            
        if(response.status === 500) {
            return 'Service unavailable. Please try later.';
        } else {
            var error = $.parseHTML( response.responseText )
            $(".editable-error-block").html(error)
        }
     },
  });
})
```

Mostly html parsing response error and injecting it inside x-editable error block.
Found in [x-editable doc, options](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable-options).